# Word for the state of being pathological

Tags: single-word-requests

As much as one could refer to a pathogenic disease by its *pathogenicity*, could one refer to a pathological state by its *pathologenicity*? Is that even a word or could be a word?

Comment: As the syllable "gen" does not appear in "pathological" then the word for the degree of being pathological (if it exists) would be "pathologicity" _not_ "pathologenicity". You could try searching the Web for "pathologicity" to see if it exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While *pathogenicity* actually refers to the ability or property of pathogens like bacteria, viruses, etc. to cause a disease, it is *pathology* that refers to the typical behavior collectively considering the pathological features like causes and effects of a disease.

So the word you're looking for should be *Pathology* since 'pathologenicity' is not a word.